# In CSS grid how to expand child element beyond parent's container

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid, say of 3 columns, with parent container located in the middle column, can I somehow expand child to take all three columns? In my code below I want the image area took all three columns, while text took just one:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 1fr 10%;
}

.content {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.image-area {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  color: #6dae72;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="text-area">Some text</div>
    <div class="image-area">The picture</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: why the extra div for `content`? you can have one grid and easily achieve what you want

Comment: Grids only work between a parent and direct children, `.image-area` is not a direct child of `.grid`.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I use extra div because my real project has quite complex structure with lot of sections and images (some should fill the whole page, others should be within the parent section boundaries), hence I try to do this. But I didn't know grids work only between parents and their direct children, I'll try to restructure my DOM accordingly.

Comment: @DmitryVeremchuk did you ever find a solution to this? i am facing the same issue with Tailwind Typography